# CSS: How do I 'raise' the last photo in this page?

Tags: css

I am trying to display four photos in this page:

http://progenygenealogy.com/products/family-tree-charts/photo-gallery-2.aspx

How can I get the photo on the bottom left, to rise up and fill the gap above it? What combination of "floats" do I use?

[image]

Here is an synopsis of the CSS:

```
<img style="float: left;" src="/portals/0/images/Gallery/Shanahan family circle.jpg" />
<img style="float: left;" src="/portals/0/images/Gallery/WC2.jpg" />
<img style="float: left;" src="/portals/0/images/Gallery/WC3.jpg" />
<img style="float: left;" src="/portals/0/images/Gallery/LT.jpg" />
```

Comment: You have improper HTML syntax in your question. I'm guessing it is just a typo when copying your code over, but it should be fixed nonetheless.

Comment: Floats behave that way – you could try and “fix” it using a negative `margin-top` on the image, but that’ll only work if you know the image dimensions beforehand. For more complex/dynamic situations, you should look into _jQuery Masonry_.

Comment: Thanks @ Mike K - I had edited the sample for simplicity, and dropped the closing quotes. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for general solution (it means you don´t know image size, image count and don´t want to use negative top margin manually), you have to use `multicolumn` (supported in IE9+), in non-IE browsers with prefix.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

In this case you can use negative top margin, but it has to be set manually or counted by JS. Pure-CSS solution except the one I write above doesn´t exists.

Comment: Thank you - negative margin is too much fiddling, I will try the multicolumn.